# Terminate Linux process using Python - ffmpeg to terminate a live stream to Youtube

Tags: python, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, youtube

I'm using Raspberry Pi to live stream to Youtube. I use Python and this is my script.

```
import time
import os
key = 'YouTube' 

loader='ffmpeg -f pulse -1 alsa output.platform-bcm2835 audio.analog-stereo.monitor f xllgrab -framerate 24 -video size 740x480-B etc....' + key) 
proc= os.system(loader) 
process_id = proc.pid

print('Running'.process_id)
time.sleep (60)
proc.terminate()
import sys
sys.exit("Error message")
```

The script works. However, when I try and terminate it, it remains streaming even though the script finishes.

I also tried terminating the script process_id. However it doesn't stop the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I use Python `subprocess` and that has never caused a problem in Linux (well, limited to pytest on GitHub Action to be honest):

```py
import time
import subprocess as sp
import shlex

key = 'YouTube' 

# this doesn't look like a valid FFmpeg command. Use the version which 
# successfully streamed data
loader='ffmpeg -f pulse -1 alsa output.platform-bcm2835 audio.analog-stereo.monitor f xllgrab -framerate 24 -video size 740x480-B etc....' + key) 

proc= sp.Popen(shlex.split(loader))

print(f'Running{proc.pid}')
time.sleep (60)
proc.terminate() # or proc.kill()

import sys
sys.exit("Error message")
```

If it is pulse or x11grab device refusing to terminate, you may need to 'kill' it instead.

Comment: When I convert the loader string - to this `loader = ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'pulse', '-i', 'alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_audio.analog-stereo.monitor', '-f', 'x11grab', '-framerate', '24', '-video_size', '740x480', '-i', ':0.0', '-f', 'flv', '-b:v', '1024K', '-framerate', '60', '-s', '740x480', 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/',key]` I get the following error:` Duration: N/A, start: 1646602371.360485, bitrate: 272793 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 740x480, 272793 kb/s, 24 fps, 23.58 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/: Input/output error
:`

Comment: You should call `sp.Popen` not `sp.run` (sorry, corrected on my post). (Although the error doesn't make sense to me, update your post, adding the description of your changes will help.

Comment: I tried `loader = ['ffmpeg','-f','pulse','-1','alsa','output.platform-bcm2835','audio.analog-stereo.monitor','-f','xllgrab','-framerate','24','-video','-size','740x480','-i', ':0.0','-f','flv','-b:v','1024K','-framerate','60','-s','740x480','rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/',key]
` but I got `Unrecognized option '1'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: I was wondering about `-1` option as I've never seen it before (as well as the subsequent terms. Check with [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse) and make sure it is what you want to do. Also `key` at the end doesn't make any sense either.